# GWT deploy to google App Engine get a 404 error

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, deployment

I'm trying to learn how to deploy an GWT application to Google App Engine.
I'm using GWT 2.4 + eclipse with Java 7.

I have basically a static page with a button that doesn't do anything.

```
public class Test1 implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
        final Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
        RootPanel.get().add(sendButton);
  }
}
```

I have created my application `istoeumtestedenome`, and in localhost it works. I have deployed it to App Engine with no errors. But when I try to access the page `http://istoeumtestedenome.appspot.com/`, a 404 error is displayed.

What can I do?

Comment: Any info? Like what does the upload procedure post? You can check at the online logs to see if there is anything there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things that could have gone wrong. The first things that come to mind:

1. Your static HTML file (host page) is in the wrong place (folder).
2. You did not specify a welcome page - or there are some other problems - in your web.xml file.

Go to your Admin Console for App Engine, and click on the logs to see what goes wrong.

Comment: ok it was the web.xml 

thanks, i had to be more carefull with that :P